# How to know if an sprite stopped being touched because it moved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I need to know if the user is touching a sprite. I can easily tell if he lifts his finger or moves his finger out:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"button"]) {
             // Sprite stopped being touched
            return;
        }
}
```

However I'm clueless about how to know if the touch ends because the sprite moves out while the user keeps his finger in place. I image I should somehow check inside my update method but I don't know how:

```
// Called before each frame is rendered
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     // Check if the user is holding the sprite
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: touchesEnded:withEvent:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for something like this below. There are myriad ways to come at the problem, but here's a basic way to think about it. Depending on the actual complexity of your game, you might need to do some state checking to protect performance, but you get the gist:

```
//in touchesBegan and touchesMoved update a property:
_lastTouchPoint = //the touch point in scene, etc, blah blah
//if you care about a specific sprite you could also store it:
_someMovingSprite = theSpriteIJustTouchedOrCareAbout;

//in update
if (CGRectContainsPoint(_someMovingSprite.frame, _lastTouchPoint)) {
    //the touch is inside the rect of the sprite
}
//OR

NSArray *spritesContainingTheTouchPoint = [self nodesAtPoint:_lastTouchPoint];

if (spritesContainingTheTouchPoint.count == 0) {
    //no sprites are being touched
}else{
    for (SKSpriteNode *spriteContainingTouch in spritesContainingTheTouchPoint) {
        //do something to sprite
    }
}



-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    CGPoint location = [_lastTouchPoint locationInNode:self];
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(_sprite.frame, location)) {
        @NSLog(@"Sprite Released");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, CH Buckingham thanks for your solution. I'll edit it to show exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has the documentation on every touch event they provide. The method you're looking for is [touchesEnded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded%3awithEvent%3a)

Handle it the same way you handle touchesMoved and call any methods you need in order to notify the node that it is no longer being touched.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"button"]) {
        // Notify the node that the touch has stopped
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi Steven, this only works if the user releases his finger. If the sprite moves out but the user keeps his finger on the screen this doesn't do anything. That's what I'm trying to know.

Comment: The location of the node is irrelevant to how touches are handled. I am probably not understanding you correctly here. Are you trying to detect whether the node has left the viewport?

Comment: No, just imagine someone touches a sprite that is on the top of the screen, then he doesn't move his finger nor lift it, that wouldn't fire anything. However if the sprite moves to the bottom of the screen, the user is no longer touching the sprite. I cannot figure out how to detect when this happens.

Comment: So you want to detect if the users finger is on top of the node?